# How to return columns based on selection or add that as parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, dmv

I am trying to capture sql server waits from dmv [sys-dm-exec-requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in a stored procedure to run over time.

Later i display that in UI as a view. Currently it returns over 30 columns from the proc created which is simply selecting the data from that view.

How can i add a parameters, lets say which gives me flexibility to also make a choice in which columns user might be interested to see on dashboard?

Comment: This should be defined in the report, *not* the procedure. You can't parametrise the columns that are returned from a dataset; it must be well defined. If you "had" to, you would need to use dynamic SQL to construct the query with the relevant columns; I strongly recommend against this. Use your reporting tool to define the visibility of the columns in the application based on the parameters.

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks for your comment. Here the dashboard is Grafana and i checked there is no option to filter in data set like in SSRS. Therefore was looking how i can get this done in SP itself

Comment: Like I said, I *strongly* recommend against the idea; you would have to use Dynamic SQL. As a self declared Newbie, that is not a path you should be going down yet.

Comment: @Newbie-DBA Sorry if you've already looked at this (I'm not familiar with Grafana) but is this what you need to do your filtering client-side?  https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/add-ad-hoc-filters/  Filtering is a basic reporting feature, it would really surprise me if Grafana doesn't support it.

Comment: @squillman- Yes i checked but as mentioned ":Ad hoc filter variables only work with Prometheus, Loki, InfluxDB, and Elasticsearch data sources."